# slice a dictionary on elements contained within item arrays

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, slice

Say I have a dict of country -> [cities] (potentially an ordered dict):

```
{'UK': ['Bristol', 'Manchester' 'London', 'Glasgow'],
 'France': ['Paris', 'Calais', 'Nice', 'Cannes'],
 'Germany': ['Munich', 'Berlin', 'Cologne']
}
```

The number of keys (countries) is variable: and the number of elements cities in the array, also variable. The resultset comes from a 'search' on city name so, for example, a search on "San%" could potentially meet with 50k results (on a worldwide search)

The data is to be used to populate a select2 widget --- and I'd like to use its paging functionality...

Is there a smart way to slice this such that `[3:8]` would yield:

```
{'UK': ['Glasgow'],
 'France': ['Paris', 'Calais', 'Nice', 'Cannes'],
 'Germany': ['Munich']
}
```

(apologies for the way this question was posed earlier -- I wasn't sure that the real usage would clarify the issue...)

Comment: Are there always just these 3 a b and c entries in the dict? Never more never less?

Comment: What is the logic behind this? Why does [3:8] yield that result?

Comment: By concatenating the 'child` arrays/lists you'd get [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....]. I'm trying to preserve the 'structure' whilst taking chunks (essentially limit/offset) out of it.

Comment: Basically you want to combine all lists in 1 big list, slice that list and then somehow reassign the result back to their original key in the dict?

Comment: It's still not clear to me what the rule is.  Maybe if you posted the non-smart version, which might be clunky but does what you want, we could think of ways to improve it?

Comment: That doesn't explain what role you want 3 and 11 to play.  What happened to the number 5 in your example?  What happened to 8?

Comment: His example output and input were a little messed up, he fixed the input but I think he forgot to fix the output

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, as talked about in the comments, this should do it

```
from pprint import pprint

def slice_dict(d,a, b):
  big_list = []
  ret_dict = {}
  # Make one big list of all numbers, tagging each number with the key
  # of the dict they came from.
  for k, v in d.iteritems():
    for n in v:
      big_list.append({k:n})
  # Slice it
  sliced = big_list[a:b]

  # Put everything back in order
  for k, v in d.iteritems():
    for subd in sliced:
      for subk, subv in subd.iteritems():
        if k == subk:
          if k in ret_dict:
            ret_dict[k].append(subv)
          else:
            ret_dict[k] = [subv]

  return ret_dict

d = {
  'a': [1, 2, 3, 4],
  'b': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  'c': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
}

x = slice_dict(d, 3, 11)
pprint(x)
```

---

```
$ python slice.py 
{'a': [4], 'b': [5, 6], 'c': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]}
```

The output is a little different from your example output, but that's because the dict was not ordered when it was passed to the function. It was a-c-b, that's why b is cut off at 6 and c is not cut off